# WP PHP Form Fields are missing. Where are they?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

This is a hopeful question.  I am really, really PHP inexperienced.  But I am trying to teach myself a thing or two.  The organization I work for uses a WP site.   I regularly work on it.  I mostly do HTML and CSS (stuff I know about) but I was just digging around in the background and came across something I don't understand at all.

I made a test page here:  http://all4ed.org/webinar-event/test-2/

There are two forms on the page.  The first ends in a "submit button," the second ends in a "Register Button."

So far so good.  I dug around the backend of the WP files, and found the content-webinar.php file and saw that it pulled the form in as an include with:

```
// The registration form. ?>
    <?php if ($registration_required == 'yes'): ?>
        <?php include ('assets/includes/webinar/inc-block-registration-form.php'); ?>
    <?php endif;
```

Good, so far.

I went to the "inc-block-registration-form.php" file and here's where it gets weird:

The first form is done with this code:

```
<form class="webinar-registration" action="<?= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?>" method="get">
      <div>
        <p>
          <label for="token">Token</label>
          <input type="text" name="token" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <button>Submit</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    </form>
```

This looks exactly like I thought it would.  The second form is written like this:

```
  <form class="webinar-registration" action="<?= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?>" method="post">
      <div>
        <?php if ($webinars->error) : ?>
        <p class="error"><?= $webinars->error ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php foreach ($webinars->form_data as $data) : ?>
          <p><?= $webinars->build($data) ?></p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <p>
          <button>Register</button>
          <input type="hidden" name="webinars_registration_submitted" value="<?= $post->ID ?>" />
          <input type="hidden" name="webinars_registration_title" value="<?= get_the_title() ?>" />
          <input type="hidden" name="webinars_registration_url" value="<?= get_permalink() ?>" />

          <!-- fields necessary for AA -->
            <input type="hidden" name="webinars_user_id" value="<?= get_current_user_id() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="webinars_type" value="<?= get_field('webinar_type') ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="webinars_post_id" value="<?= get_the_ID () ?>" />
        </p>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Huh????  Where is the "Your Name", "Your E-mmail Address," "Organization," "City, State," or "Question (This is optional)"

How does this work?  Where is it pulling those fields from.  Any insight would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Im guessing the fields are defined in the `$webinars->form_data` array

Comment: And probably the output is returned from `$webinars->build($data)` - the `<?= ` is to print out the statement